# elasticsearch autosuggest returning tricky JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch

I'm running a node.js server that sends queries to an elasticsearch instance.  Here is an example of the JSON returned by the query:

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 9290,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "suggest": {
        "postSuggest": [
            {
                "text": "a",
                "offset": 0,
                "length": 1,
                "options": [
                    {
                        "text": "Academic Librarian",
                        "score": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "Able Seamen",
                        "score": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "Academic Dean",
                        "score": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "Academic Deans-Registrar",
                        "score": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "Accessory Designer",
                        "score": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to create an array containing each job title as a string.  I've run into this weird behavior that I can't figure out.  Whenever I try to pull values out of the JSON, I can't go below `options` or everything comes back as undefined.

For example:

`arr.push(results.suggest.postSuggest)` will push just what you'd expect: all the stuff inside postSuggest.

`arr.push(results.suggest.postSuggest.options)` will come up as undefined even though I can see it when I run it without `.options`.  This is also true for anything below `.options`.

I think it may be because `.options` is some sort of built-in function that acts on variables, so instead of seeing options as JSON and is instead trying to run a function on `results.suggest.postSuggest`

Comment: `postSuggest` is an array (brackets, `[..]`) containing an object (braces, `{..}`). You'll need to access an index of the array first – `postSuggest[0].options`. – [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Fixed my problem, thank you.  I never registered that it was an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> arr.push(results.suggest.postSuggest.options)

`postSuggest` is an array of object.`options` inside `postSuggest` is also array of object. So first you need to get postSuggest by `postSuggest[0]` and then 
`postSuggest[0].options` to get array of `options`

This below snippet can be usefule

```
 var myObj = {..}
// used jquery just to demonstrate postSuggest  is an Array
console.log($.isArray(myObj.suggest.postSuggest)) //return true
var getPostSuggest =myObj.suggest.postSuggest  //Array of object
var getOptions = getPostSuggest[0].options; // 0 since it contain only one element
console.log(getOptions.length) ; // 5 , contain 5 objects
getOptions.forEach(function(item){
  document.write("<pre>Score is "+ item.score + " Text</pre>")
})
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eb98bk65/1/)